# How to show the zero in 0.24

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi so i have been using to_char to round off my decimal to 2 digit. However, when it encounter value like 0.24 it only display .24 and ignore the 0. How should i make it to display 0.24?

to_char(0.24,'9,999,999.99')unit_price

Comment: you want `'9,999,990.99'`, a `9` is an optional,  a `0` represents a definietly shown number, even if non would need to be shown as the `.24` in your case.

Comment: wow thanks, that really solve my issue

Comment: Or even `'999G990D99'` to avoid hardcoding ',' and '.' as the thousands and decimal separator charactors. `G` and `D` reflect the current setting for `nls_numeric_characters`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.24,'0.00') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: You're applying to_char to a string

Comment: My bad. It was a type. :)

Answer (score -2):

Try `lpad(to_char(0.24,'9,999,999.99')unit_price, 4)`

Comment: to fiddle with strings is not the right way to format a number